# Unable to get cell frame or constraints in cellForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, autolayout

**Problem**

I am trying to adjust some constraints of a UIButton, placed inside a UITableViewCell, based on certain conditions.

I am doing this inside the datasource method `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. However, it seems like my cell's frame is always coming back as `(0, 0, 0, 0)`, which means I can't get the constraints for any subviews to adjust them, unless I scroll.

**What I Have Tried**

I have [created and uploaded a simple project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wsbamuhcb61nqee/CellFrameTest.zip?dl=0) in an attempt to nail down the problem. Here is the code from `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    TestCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"TestCell"];
    cell.label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", indexPath.row];

    NSLog(@"CELL FRAME: %f, INDEXPATH: %lu, CONSTRAINTS: %lu", CGRectGetWidth(cell.frame), indexPath.row, cell.label.constraints.count);

    return cell;
}
```

**Results**

When I run the project I see the following log:

```
CELL FRAME WIDTH: 0.000000, INDEXPATH: 0, CONSTRAINTS: 0
```

However, once I scroll, I start seeing something like:

```
CELL FRAME WIDTH: 320.000000, INDEXPATH: 7, CONSTRAINTS: 2
```

**Question**

What am I doing wrong here? How can I get the constraints of my cell's subviews to adjust them, without having to scroll first?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Adjust the cell in the `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` method.

In the `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method, the cell's frame isn't setup yet and the cell isn't yet added to the table view. It's too soon.

Better yet would be to put the responsibility inside the implementation of the `TestCell` class.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer. With `willDisplayCell` now I seem to be getting the frame correctly, but the constraints are still coming back as 0. Any ideas?

Comment: Never mind. I had not set up the constraints properly. Once I fixed my constraints, they began to show up just fine too. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to observe too early. The cell is not expected to have a proper frame at this time. After `cellForRowAtIndexPath'` is called, the tableview still does work under the hood to size the cell, and that will result in a frame change.

Try making this call in `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` instead

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer. With `willDisplayCell` now I seem to be getting the frame correctly, but the constraints are still coming back as 0. Any ideas?

Comment: Never mind. I had not set up the constraints properly. Once I fixed my constraints, they began to show up just fine too. Thank you! +1