# How to check UILabel whether is truncated or not in UITableViewCell?

Tags: swift, uitableview, uilabel

I have auto size fit tableViewCell, and how to know it's UILabel whether is truncated or not. 
I also get true that using my UILabel extension code. 
 
Please tell me what's wrong with my code?
 
When I scroll the tableview and print the correct bool.
Have any idea to let me get the correct bool at first init time.
Thanks.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

let itemCount: Int = 10
let tableView = UITableView()
let cellWithButton = "cellWithButton"
var isExpand: Bool = false
var expandingStateArray: [Bool] = []

let textArray: [String] = ["If you read and listen to two articles every day, your reading and listening skills can immm If you read and listen to two articles every day, your reading and listening skills can immm If you read and listen to two articles every day, your reading and listening skills can immm If you read and listen to two articles every day, your reading and listening skills can immm If you read and listen to two articles every day, your reading and listening skills can immm", "If you read and listen to two articles every day", "If you read and listen to two articles every day, your reading and listening skills can immm If you read and listen to two articles every day", "If you read and listen to two articles every day, your reading and listening skills can immm If you read and listen to two articles every day", "If you read and listen to two articles every day, your reading and listening skills can immm If you read and listen to two articles every day", "If you read and listen to two articles every day, your reading and listening skills can immm If you read and listen to two articles every day", "If you read and listen to two articles every day, your reading and listening skills can immm If you read and listen to two articles every day", "If you read and listen to two articles every day, your reading and listening skills can immm If you read and listen to two articles every day", "If you read and listen to two articles every day, your reading and listening skills", "If you read and listen to two articles every day, your reading and listening skills can immm If you read and listen to two articles every day, your reading and listening skills can immm If you read and listen to two articles every day, your reading and listening skills can immm If you read and listen to two articles every day, your reading and listening skills can immm If you read and listen to two articles every day, your reading and listening skills can immm"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    for _ in 0...itemCount-1 {
        let bool = false
        expandingStateArray.append(bool)
    }

    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.allowsSelection = false
    tableView.separatorInset = .zero
    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44
    tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    tableView.register(WithButtonTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellWithButton)

    self.view.addSubview(tableView)

    tableView.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
        make.top.left.right.bottom.equalToSuperview()
    }
}

@objc func btnPressed(sender: UIButton) {

    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: sender.tag, section: 0)

    if self.isExpand == false {

        self.isExpand = true

        expandingStateArray[sender.tag] = true

    } else {
        self.isExpand = false

        expandingStateArray[sender.tag] = false
    }

    tableView.beginUpdates()
    tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)
    tableView.endUpdates()

}  
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return itemCount
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellWithButton, for: indexPath) as! WithButtonTableViewCell

    cell.titleLabel.text = textArray[indexPath.row]
    cell.expandButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(btnPressed), for: .touchUpInside)
    cell.expandButton.tag = indexPath.row

    if expandingStateArray[indexPath.row] {
        cell.titleLabel.numberOfLines = 0
        cell.expandButton.setTitle("Close.", for: .normal)
    }else{
        cell.titleLabel.numberOfLines = 2
        cell.expandButton.setTitle("Show More.", for: .normal)
    }

    print("===) \(indexPath.row) istrun: \(cell.titleLabel.isTruncated)")  //always get true at first time ,when I scroll and get false successfully.

    return cell
}
}

extension UILabel {

func countLabelLines(label: UILabel) -> Int {
    self.layoutIfNeeded()
    let myText = label.text! as NSString

    let rect = CGSize(width: label.bounds.width, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude)
    let labelSize = myText.boundingRect(with: rect, options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.font: label.font], context: nil)

    return Int(ceil(CGFloat(labelSize.height) / label.font.lineHeight))
}

var isTruncated: Bool {

    guard let labelText = text else {
        return false
    }

    let labelTextSize = (labelText as NSString).boundingRect(
        with: CGSize(width: frame.size.width, height: .greatestFiniteMagnitude),
        options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin,
        attributes: [.font: font],
        context: nil).size

    return labelTextSize.height > bounds.size.height
}

}
```

Comment: Why do you want to know if it's truncated or not? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: @Cesare if truncated I will show the button "show more", if not truncated I will hide the button. So I need to check this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't be entirely certain of the width of your cells when you first display your table view because the user might have the iOS device set up for portrait or for landscape (and they can also rotate it at will).

What you should be doing here is add your "Show More" button to all cells and then show or hide it depending on if the text is truncated.

[And the right place to show or hide that button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27757660/unable-to-get-cell-frame-or-constraints-in-cellforrowatindexpath) is in the [`UITableViewDelegate` `willDisplay:forRowAt:` function](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614883-tableview).

Perhaps something like:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, 
            willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, 
               forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) 
{
    // previously set the titleLabel to the text in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`
    let labelIsTruncated = cell.titleLabel.isTruncated
    // if label is truncated, isHidden should be false.
    cell.showMoreButton.isHidden = (labelIsTruncated == false)
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work when switching between portrait and landscape modes.